# Німеччина чи Германія?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, власні-назви

Мене недавно виправили, коли я використав слово "Германія", обгрунтовуючи це тим, що в українській мові правильно говорити лише "Німеччина".

**Питання:** Чи дозволяється користуватися обома назвами в українській мові? Чи є між ними якась різниця у використавнні?

Answer (score 6):

Імовірно, «Германія» застосовується лише до цивілізації стародавніх германців ([див. у Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%8F)). [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) подають слово «Германія» з приміткою «**антична** назва країни…».

Тож, наскільки я розумію, застосовувати можна лише в якомусь дуже переносному/поетичному сенсі. Як ми в загальному спілкуванні не називаємо Україну Руссю чи Італію Римом.